# jQuery page keeps refreshing on click

Tags: php, jquery

So I have a table where I have hyperlinks which link to the same page with an url parameter and perform a query effecting the table. And I'm trying to reload the contents of the page without it refreshing.

```
<div class="content">
<table class="tg">
     <tr>
          <td><a href="?sort=name">Name</a></td>
          <td> ..
     </tr>
     <?php
          foreach($stmt as $row) {
               echo "<tr>"
               echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
               echo "<td> ..
               echo "</tr>"
          }
     ?>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click', function(e){  
        $('.content').load('index.php .content');
        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I click on the link, it will work once without a refresh and then after that will refresh the page once and so on.

Comment: I think that when refreshing .content into itself, you lose the jQuery 'click' binding... You might have to re-bind the click event upon refresh.

Comment: try delegating the click event to .content so you don't have to rebind the event after the content loads.  `$('.content').on('click', 'a' ,function(e){});`

Comment: Did you try moving your all `scripts` at the top of your file?

Comment: @spaniol6 This worked, thank you.